# howto use vaxis in google charts materialview

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have been fiddling with a particle photon, posting data to sparkfun.com

To display this data I am trying to use google.visualization. But I cant seem to get the axis behaving as I want it to. 
 see (but wait a while it is slow): https://www.hanscees.com/photon/charts-data-sparkfunA.html

I want the caxis to show not 1K, but 1010 and so on.  here is my code:

```
 function drawChart1() {

        var public_key = 'yA0EjKV3owhKNx1NlN3w';

        // JSONP request
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
          //data: {page: 1},
      data: {'lte' : {'timestamp' : 'now - 4 hours'}},
          dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(function (results) {

              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

              data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Pressure');

              $.each(results, function (i, row) {
                data.addRow([
                  (new Date(row.timestamp)),
              parseFloat(row.hectopascals)
             ]);
                            }); // each row

    // see https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts
    var materialOptions = {
              chart: { title: 'Barometer Pressure'},
              width: 550,
              height: 500,
              series: {
               // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
               0: {axis: 'Pressure'}
               },
               axes: {
               // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
                y: {
                       Pressure: {label: 'Pressure (Hpa)'}
                   }
               },
          vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
          hAxis: {color: '#333', count: 8}

         };

         var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(ChartDivBaro);
        materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);

          }); // results



      } // jsondata
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, most `vAxis` options simply do not work on *material* charts...

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

recommend using a *core* chart instead...

you can use the following option to get the look and feel *close* to *material*

```
theme: 'material'
```

Comment: solved it without material: <code>
    var options = {title:'Pressure Outside',
                       width:550,
                       height:300,
   vAxis: {format: '0'}
     };
         var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart1').get(0));
            chart.draw(data, options); // draw data
    }); // results

Answer (score 0):

solved it without material:

```
var options = {title:'Pressure Outside',
width:550,
height:300,
vAxis: {format: '0'}
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart1').get(0));
chart.draw(data, options); // draw data
}); // results
```

[image: image about pressure]